# How to get the size of an drawable image in android

Tags: java, android, android-image

currently i m working in drawable images in android, and now i want to get the size the drawable image in KB , how can i get it, any ideas are welcome.

Here i m getting the default application icons and storing in an drawable array, is creating a new file for each icon for getting length is a good idea? Please suggest any better idea,thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281242/android-how-can-i-get-a-image-that-is-in-drawable-its-size-in-kb-name-and-ext

Comment: Hi lalit, i think in that question itself there is no any clear answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u have to make it a file. But not sure whether it works

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "temp" + File.separator);
                    root.mkdirs();
                    File file= new File(root, "temp.png");

FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                                 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);//bmp is bitmap of ur image
                         fOut.flush();
                         fOut.close();
```

Using `file.length()` should give you the file size.

Comment: he wants from drawable not from sdcard.

Comment: yea. i asked him to save it to sd card and check for the file size

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea. Convert the drawable image to a byte array... the array length is the size of the drawable image in bytes. Not sure if there is a better way...

Comment: That's the only way I know of. If you need it in KB, just divide the `array.length` by 1024. :)

Comment: hi alex, i got the expected result through this technique, Thanks for ur reply.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work in all situations but you can use this:

```
Drawable d;
long kbsize = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap().getByteCount() / 1024;
```